# Primes of the form p ≡ 1 (mod 6). (puzzle word problem)

Tags: number-theory

Those cards are at it again. The quest to cut down the complexity of possible primes in Wonderland continues. Having been previously burnt modulo 4 the Queen of Hearts decided to move to modulo 6; henceforth only those primes of the form p ≡ 1 (mod 6) would be used in Wonderland. The existence of all others would be denied. The Queen ofcourse checked and indeed there seemed to be many such values; 7, 19, 31, 37, . . .

Of course “safe” or “strong primes” were still desirable and the White Rabbit was set the task of finding 1 modulo 6 Sophie Germain primes for cryptographic purposes and he had been assured by the Mad Hatter that this should be easy. Hatter’s argument went as follows;no less than G. H Hardy had conjectured, and given supporting reasons, that the asymptotic behaviour of the number of Sophie Germain primes has the value $π_{SG}(x) ≈ Cx/(log x)^2$.

If this were true and since primes of the form ±1 (mod 6) in the Queen’s mandated list make up approximately half of all possible primes, the same should be true of Germain primes; merely a factor of two different. The March Hare wasn’t so sure; he didn’t like these hand-waving kinds of argument and didn’t trust the Hatter’s logic. Can you help the folks in Wonderland out?

Comment: I do not understand the purpose of the riddle. The existence of infinite Sophie Germain primes is a conjecture with the same complexity of the twin primes conjecture (i.e. too much for the man in the street nowadays); on the other hand the almost-equidistribution of primes in APs is well-known and if $p\equiv 1\pmod{6}$ then $2p+1$ cannot be a prime.